# How should the Marshal run the Wanted Hindrance?

Tags: savage-worlds

Within Savage Worlds, there is a hindrance called *wanted*. How is the Marshal to run that hindrance, and how does he know when the character is wanted or not?

It seems like if we don't have a decent way to figure this out, two players in my weekly game are gonna have problems and I'd like to avoid the confusion before it comes up :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, the players need to define why and where they are wanted.  It may just be outstanding fines in one city, in which case he needs to keep his head down when the local authorities are in sight.  He may have murdered a noble and a bounty has placed on his capture.  This requires staying low pretty much everywhere he goes.

Whatever the player decides, it has to be okayed with the Marshal/Game Master.  If it's so insignificant that it would never come up during the game, then it's not a hindrance.  The GM can also decide whether their description warrants a minor or major hindrance.  A *Wanted (Minor)* character would be harassed in many places, or actively hunted in one region.  A *Wanted (Major)* character would be hunted wherever he goes.

So going off of the *Wanted* description the GM and player agree on, it should be clear in what regions the hindrance comes into effect.  A confrontation could occur any time the party gets the attention of those seeking him, or maybe just by failing a random roll (eg. a Stealth test daily to avoid casual detection.)  By timing the encounter, you can make things very interesting.  (eg. Police enter the bar you're in while you're in an important discussion with an important NPC.)  If they're wanted by the organisation they're actively trying to disrupt, then the organisation is applying special attention to capturing them, perhaps even outsourcing.

Someone who takes the *Wanted* hindrance is asking (whether knowingly or not) for more problems.

Comment: You are using the term Marshal, so I presume you are playing this in *Deadlands*. The version of Wanted in that setting is slightly different because there is a monetary reward associated with the capture or death (i.e. they have a wanted poster). Make sure that there is an agreement for how much the bounty is worth, where it can be collected, and whether it's valid if the character is dead or alive.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  I assumed Marshal was a non-English translation of GM.

Comment: I'm not sure what the non-English versions of *Savage Worlds* use, but with the English version, the default is Gamemaster. *Deadlands* uses the Wild West term Marshal instead, which is what led me to think you were playing in that setting.